# How to access a variable defined in root build.gradle file from subproject build.gradle using kotlin dsl?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

A variable defined in root build.gradle fille

```
def a = 1
```

and i want access the variable a in subproject's build.gradle.ktl file.
Notice subproject's gradle file uses kotlin dsl.